# Pandas deep copy and scikit learn min max scaler

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am trying to do the following

```
df = pd.read_csv('a.csv')
scaler = MinMaxScaler()

df_copy = df.copy(deep=True)

for i in range(1, len(df)):

  df_chunk = df_copy.iloc[i,i+10]

  df_chunk = scaler.fit_transform (df_chunk)
```

so each df_chunk should be a scaled data frame.

The issue is that some are not scaled correctly.

If I were to plot the scaled data points, a properly scaled data frame will look like a range of numbers scattered between 0 and 1 sort of evenly. But the data frames I get are in 2 extremes, with the first ~80% of the numbers in the 0.9 range, while the others near the 0.1 range.

So it feels like the first ~80% of the data got scaled twice by the scaler. I have already tried using pandas deep copy to solve this, but it doesn't seem to help.

If you have any idea, why?

I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure why you want to apply the scaler on chunks of your data. If you fear that your CSV may be too large, you would want to read the CSV by chunks in the `read_csv` operation and process those chunks.

Now onto your issue. You're re-fitting your scaler on every chunk which is why you're getting the weird results. You either have to fit the entire data with your scaler, or you have to online fit the data using the [`partial_fit`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.partial_fit) method.

I'll provide you both solutions.

**Solution #1: read and fit the entire data**

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

scaler = MinMaxScaler()

df = pd.read_csv('a.csv')
df_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(df)
```

**Solution #2: read the csv by chunks, and online train**

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

scaler = MinMaxScaler()

# first read the csv by chunks and update the scaler
for chunk in pd.read_csv('a.csv', chunksize=10):
    scaler.partial_fit(chunk)

# read the csv again by chunks to transform the chunks
for chunk in pd.read_csv('a.csv', chunksize=10):
    transformed = scaler.transform(chunk)
    # not too sure what you want to do after this
    # but you can either print the results of the transformation
    # or write the transformed chunk to a new csv
```

Comment: Thanks Scratch, the scaling by chunk is intentional, apologies for not explaining this upfront. I will try your suggestion on reading in by chunk, thank you.